# Using the returned object / list from Stripe

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I have a `Stripe_List` that is returned from a `\Stripe_InvoiceItem::all()` request.

```
$invoice_items = \Stripe_InvoiceItem::all();
return $invoice_items;
```

This gives me the following:

```
Stripe_List JSON: {
    "object": "list",
    "has_more": false,
    "url": "\/v1\/invoiceitems",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "ii_123456789abcdefg",
            "object": "invoiceitem",
            "date": 1424714643,
            "amount": 0,
            "livemode": false,
            "proration": false,
            "currency": "gbp",
            "customer": "cus_xyz12345",
            "description": "Invoice Item",
            "metadata": [],
            "invoice": "in_abcdefghijklmnop",
            "subscription": null,
            "quantity": null,
            "plan": null
        }
    ]
}
```

But, I'm unsure how to loop through the results.

```
return $invoice_items->data; // returns [{}]
return $invoice_items->data(); // Call to undefined method Stripe_List::data()
return $invoice_items->get('data'); // returns Call to undefined method Stripe_List::get()
return json_decode($invoice_items); // returns empty string
```

I think its just a major gap in my fundamental php knowledge, but after a lot of googling I'm struggling to find any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$invoice_items->data` should be what you want. It may not be rendering the string preview properly. If you print `$invoice_items->data[0]` do you get the correct object?

Comment: I think that was exactly it. Everything __was__ there, but, also, not showing using the methods above. The invoice items showed up just fine once i started looping through everything.

Comment: Filed an issue...we should make this work better: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/issues/149